# Incoming connection queue on WebSpehere

Tags: web-services, websphere

I've an application that exposes 1 web service running on WebSphere. I want to limit the maximum clients available to X with something like a connection queue. I've read about "[connection pool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rwbs_httptransportprop.html)" but it's just for outgoing connection.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the maximum amount of TCP connections allowed with the following TCP Channel setting:

Maximum open connections

You can find how to set it here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/urun_chain_typetcp.html?lang=en

This will limit any connection not just the ones to your WebService, if you are serving more than one WebService in the server this may not be a good setting to change as it will limit all connections to WAS.

By Default WAS allows 20,000 open connections. You can limit it lets say to 1,000 if that is the maximum you want to serve.

Answer (score 0):

I'll come at this from another angle. I'm assuming you want to limit the maximum concurrent client requests that can be processed at the application server? In WebSphere the WebContainer thread pool is the way to limit the number of concurrent connections that can be processed at anyone time. So if you wanted to only allow 10 concurrent connections then set the WebContainer thread pool max to 10. Be aware that will be for every cluster member in the cluster so if you have 10 JVMs then there will be 100 threads that can process at one time.

Same caveat applies this will affect all applications that need to use the WebContainer thread pool. One way to get around this is to only deploy the service and no other apps. Let the other apps get their own JVMs with appropriate thread pool settings.